# PyTorch: How to check if some weights are not changed during training?

Tags: pytorch

How can I check if some weights are not changed during training in PyTorch?

As I understand one option can be just dump model weights at some epochs and check if they are changed iterating over weights, but maybe there is some simpler way?

Comment: You could set a hook to check the gradients and then you could just keep track of a counter for whether the gradient value was ever updated by counting the number of zeros.

Comment: @AnuragReddy Example would be great.

Comment: Check the answer. @mrgloom Feel free to ask or correct me if something is wrong or confusing. I might learn something from you also that way :)

Answer (score 4):

There can be two ways around this:

First

```py
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if 'weight' in name:
        temp = torch.zeros(param.grad.shape)
        temp[param.grad != 0] += 1
        count_dict[name] += temp
```

This step comes in after your `loss.backward()` step in the training module. The `count_dict[name]` dictionary keeps track of the gradient updates. You can initialize it this way before the start of training:

```py
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if 'weight' in name:
        count_dict[name] = torch.zeros(param.grad.shape)
```

Now one more way would be to register a hook function and then create the hook function where you can even update the or modify the gradients if you want to. This is not necessary to keep track of the weight updates but then if you want to do something with the gradient, it comes in handy.
Suppose, here I am randomly sparsifying the gradients.

```py
def hook_fn(grad):
    '''
    Randomly sparsify the gradients
    :param grad: Input gradient of the layer
    :return: grad_clone - the sparsified FC layer gradients
    '''
    grad_clone = grad.clone()
    temp = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(grad_clone.shape).uniform_()
    grad_clone[temp < 0.8] = 0
    return grad_clone
```

And here I give the model the hook.

```py
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if 'weight' in name:
            param.register_hook(hook_fn)
```

So, this might just sparsify the gradients for you, and you can keep track of gradients in the hook function itself in this way:

```py
def hook_func(module, input, output):
    temp = torch.zeros(output.shape)
    temp[output != 0] += 1
    count_dict[module] += temp
```

Although, I won't recommend doing this. This is generally useful in the case of visualizing the forward pass features/activations. And also, input and output can confuse because the gradient and param inputs and outputs are reversed.

Comment: Seems hook not always can be called https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998318/pytorch-in-which-cases-register-hook-can-return-none-gradient

Also what is the pros / cons of using `register_hook` instead `.grad` after `loss.backward()`?

Comment: Also if `.grad` is not `None` does it always mean that weights will be updated?

Comment: @mrgloom answering you first question - So, usually hooks are useful either in visualising the intermediate activations ( forward hooks) or in the case of backward hooks, they are useful in modifying the gradients while training itself. Suppose that, you want to gate certain updates, or have some parameters or values which can be multiplied or added to the gradients, then hooks are good. 
 Coming to question 2 - if `.grad` is not `None`, I am assuming that you set `requires_grad=False`, because what signifies update is the value of the gradient itself.

Comment: What I mean is that, the `.grad` value can be not None but at the same time it can be a mix of `0`s and other values. So, wherever the value is 0 signifies that the synapse will remain constant and won't be updated

Comment: And also in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998318/pytorch-in-which-cases-register-hook-can-return-none-gradient) you shared, I would recommend using the  `.grad` directly instead of using hooks. Since, you don't want to modify the gradients. Yeah, you can give the no grad option in a hook ( by basically making all the gradients to 0 in the hook function) :P.

Answer (score 2):

Several packages also offer automated testing for parameter updates in PyTorch models. For example the [torchtest](https://github.com/suriyadeepan/torchtest) package.

Here is a simple example from the README of [torchtest](https://github.com/suriyadeepan/torchtest):

```python
# imports
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchtest import assert_vars_change

# define variables and model
inputs = Variable(torch.randn(20, 20))
targets = Variable(torch.randint(0, 2, (20,))).long()
batch = [inputs, targets]
model = nn.Linear(20, 2)

# what are the variables?
print('Our list of parameters', [ np[0] for np in model.named_parameters() ])

# do they change after a training step?
#  let's run a train step and see
# assert statement passes if parameters are updated
assert_vars_change(
    model=model,
    loss_fn=F.cross_entropy,
    optim=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters()),
    batch=batch,
    device = 'cpu')
```

Output:

```python
Our list of parameters ['weight', 'bias']
```

-> the assert statement has passed and all relevant parameters have been updated

You can further specify which parameters you want to inspect by adding a `params` argument to `assert_vars_change`, for example to only test whether the model bias is updated specify `params=[('bias', model.bias)]`

```python
assert_vars_same(
        model=model,
        loss_fn=F.cross_entropy,
        optim=torch.optim.Adam(params_to_train),
        batch=batch,
        params=[('bias', model.bias)]
        )
```