# PyTorch: in which cases register_hook can return None gradient?

Tags: pytorch

Here is an example of using `register_hook` with `nn.Module`, also I double check gradient shape using `.grad` on weights after `loss.backward()`:

```
class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(5, 6)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layers(x)
        
        h = self.layers[0].weight.register_hook(lambda grad: print(f'DEBUG: grad hook {grad.size()}'))
        
        return out
                    
a = torch.ones(5)
a.requires_grad = True
print('a.size()', a.size())
m = MyModule()
b = m(a)
print('b.size()', b.size())
loss = b.mean() # Fake loss
loss.backward()
print('grad.size():', m.layers[0].weight.grad.size())
```

Output:

```
a.size() torch.Size([5])
b.size() torch.Size([6])
DEBUG: grad hook torch.Size([6, 5])
grad.size(): torch.Size([6, 5])
```

Here is more complex example with `torch.no_grad()` (so hook doesn't called):

```
class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(5, 5)
        )
    
    def break_grad_flow(self, x):
        with torch.no_grad():
            x = x + 1
        return x
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layers(x)
        out = self.break_grad_flow(out)
        out = out + x*0 # To overcome RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
        
        h = self.layers[0].weight.register_hook(lambda grad: print(f'DEBUG: grad hook {grad.size()}'))
        
        return out

def get_grad_size(grad):
    if grad is None:
        return None
    else:
        return grad.size()
    
a = torch.ones(5)
a.requires_grad = True
print('a.size()', a.size())
m = MyModule()
b = m(a)
print('b.size()', b.size())
loss = b.mean() # Fake loss
loss.backward()
print('grad.size():', get_grad_size(m.layers[0].weight.grad))
```

Output:

```
a.size() torch.Size([5])
b.size() torch.Size([5])
grad.size(): None
```

These outputs are valid and in second example hook is not called when gradient is None (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/register-hook-not-always-working-saving-gradients/56381/6)

But in real big project where I also have `torch.no_grad()` somewhere in the middle of the architecture (which I can't reproduce in simple example) I get `None` shape from hook and valid shape from `.grad` after `loss.backward()` which looks weird (I expect hook don't called and `None` shape from `.grad` after `loss.backward()`), so is there any reason why hook can return `None` shape?

Also if I just want to check if gradient is not `None` what are pros and cons of using `register_hook` instead of `.grad` on weights after `loss.backward()`?