# How to check that all gradients weights are zeros in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to know how to check all PyTorch neural network gradient weights to see if they are zero or not whether to continue training or not.

This may seem to be like [PyTorch: How to check if some weights are not changed during training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63962561/pytorch-how-to-check-if-some-weights-are-not-changed-during-training) but it's actually a different approach toward problem getting stuck in local minima. I don't have a clue what code I should add cause it seems a general question and I even don't know how to access gradient tensor in PyTorch.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the parameters are all zero like so:

```py
for p in model.parameters():
    if not p.all():
        ...
```

Comment: thanx for answer but i dont get it?  is model parameters just contain the gradient?!